# Setup a nexus "Site repository" as a mirror of an distant site

Tags: nexus, mirroring, hosted

I would like to set up a nexus "Site repository" as a mirror of an distant site, let's say http://www.nodejs.org/dist/.

I followed theses explanations : http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/_creating_a_site_repository.html
and I created it (named `nodejs-org-dist`).

Additionnaly, I configured the mirror tab by adding the distant url (http://www.nodejs.org/dist/) to the list of the mirrors.

Doing that, I was expecting to access this file

```
http://www.nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.33/node.exe
```

.. through this link :

```
http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/sites/nodejs-org-dist/v0.10.33/node.exe
```

But it does not seem to work at all (I get a 404).

So :

- Does this make sense to expect that behavior ?
- It is possible to do that ?
- If it is, what did I do wrong ?

I am  really new to nexus and all this repositories' world.

Thx a lot for your help.

NB: I am using Sonatype Nexus™ 2.10.0-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site repositories can not be proxied. The mirror configuration will not cause Nexus to do any proxying as you want.

Comment: Thx for your answer. That is what I figured out. But I still do not understand what does the "Mirrors" tab come for, then ?

Comment: The mirror tab in Nexus is a bit of legacy cruft at this point.  It's intended use was for the Maven Central repository. Back in the days when central was not hosted on a CDN you often had to configure a mirror in order to get reasonable performance.  When doing this, the artifact downloads would come through a mirror, but the metadata and checksum files would come from the main central instance. This would provide assurance that the mirror's artifacts hadn't been tampered with.

Now central is hosted on a CDN, so you'll get the best performance by having Nexus go directly to the central URL.